# private notes about a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Given a question on math.SE, I may or may not participate in the discussion. But, there might be some thought processes and ideas about the question (or the subsequent discussion), which I would like to make note of. A note, typically would be like this:

> Ah! look at the parity of the $n$-dimensional integer lattice and apply pigeon-hole

or this:

> slightly polished version of question xyz, nothing noteworthy

This helps when I go to a post I have posted long back or when I digging out for something specific among my favorites.

I am looking for an app/script/functionality(?) which stores all the notes(either locally or on a server). I should be able to navigate to the question from the note. When I open a question page, all my note(s) of that page should appear in a dropdown or sidebar or some mechanism. Although, I have found the necessity of this only on math.SE, please do suggest generic solutions.

PS for Mods: I am not sure this is the best place to post it. If it belongs to stackapps or something else, let me know and I will delete this and post this there.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_annotation has an overview of software for this purpose.

Comment: (If you find one of these options convenient for the task, please post it as an answer. I haven't used any of them.)

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY: Web annotation tools help. I came across 'Note Anywhere', a chrome addon which does the job for me in a simple manner. Thanks for your suggestion again.

Comment: In the meantime, there is a feature called [saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info). For each saved post you can add a note up to 500 characters. Currently both saves and the notes are private - see [this related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391888).